# Mounting Lithium Packs in Enclosures

Tags: batteries, enclosure

I am planning to use a battery cell similar to the picture below in a product I'm designing. Is it ever appropriate to mount these directly on top of a PCB? (all components will be on one side of the board, so would be mounted on bare side) Is there some sort of insulation material to wedge between the battery and board?

I guess what I'm asking is, what is the standard way of mounting cells like these?

[image]

Comment: you can mount the battery to the board by using double sided foam tape .... http://www.porcupinerc.com/assets/images/Tape/TP-003.jpg ..... for extra security, drill a hole on either side of the battery and use a nylon wire tie to secure

Comment: I figured I was overthinking this, thanks for the quick response and good answer.